# How to leave the browser open when a Behat/Mink test fails

Tags: selenium, browser, behat, mink

I'm using the `selenium2` driver to test my Drupal site using Behat/Mink in a docker container.

Using the [Selenium Standalone-Chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/) container, I can watch my behat tests fail, but the problem is that as soon as they fail, the browser is closed, which makes it harder for me to see what the problem is.

I'm running my tests like this:

```
behat --tags '@mystuff' --config=behat-myconfig.yml --strict --stop-on-failure
```

Is there a way to leave the remote-controlled browser open even when a test fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a good solution for this: [behat-fail-aid](https://packagist.org/packages/genesis/behat-fail-aid).

Add the fail aid to your FeatureContext and then run behat with the `--wait-on-failure` option:

> the --wait-on-failure={seconds} option can be used to
> investigate/inspect failures in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

By default it is not possible.

Maybe you could find some hack to do it but it is not recommended, since each scenario should be isolated and this is not a good solution at least when running some suite with multiple tests.

For one time only see if you can use the logic for `printscreen` and use a `breakpoint` instead.

Anyway, you should use a verbose (`-vvv` for Behat 3) output + ide debugger to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot whenever an error occurs using Behat hook "AfterStep".
Consider having a look at the Panther Driver or DChrome Driver.
Here you are a shortened example considering also non javascript tests (which are faster):

```
use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;

/** Context Class Definition ... */

/**
 * @AfterStep
 */
public function takeScreenShotAfterFailedStep(AfterStepScope $scope)
{
    if (99 !== $scope->getTestResult()->getResultCode()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->takeAScreenShot('error');
}


private function takeAScreenShot($prefix = 'screenshot')
{
    $baseName= sprintf('PATH_FOR_YOUR_SCREENSHOTS/%s-%s', $prefix, (new \DateTime())->format('Y_m_d_H_i_s'));

    if ($this->supportsJavascript()) {
        $extension = '.png';
        $content = $this->session->getScreenshot();
    } else {
        $extension = '.html';
        $content = $this->getSession()->getPage()->getOuterHtml();
    }
    file_put_contents(sprintf('%s%s', $baseName, $extension), $content);
}

private function supportsJavascript()
{
    return $this->getSession()->getDriver() instanceof Selenium2Driver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't leave the browser open as requested in the question. I've had problems before with screenshots when the page requires scrolling and the screenshot isn't scrolled. Also worth noting: instead of coding this oneself, [behat-fail-aid](https://packagist.org/packages/genesis/behat-fail-aid) can also do this, as can [behat-screenshot](https://packagist.org/packages/bex/behat-screenshot).

Comment: Well, I understood, that the main problem was that you could not see the entire result page when an error happened. If you need to see further information, you can set the height page with selenium or scroll to an object. Example of scrolling: With selenium you can scroll the browser to a wished css selector, hope this helps: $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('named', ['content', $content])->focus(); . Example of extending the height: $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(1440, YOUR_HEIGHT);